# How to access the same view from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'd like to know how to access a view (that is in an activity) from a fragment.

More specifically, a view starts in the activity and I want the same view to to end in the fragment. Thanks.

In Activity:

```
private View layoutProgress;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

layoutProgress = findViewById(R.id.layout_progress);

layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

when the button is pressed:

```
fragment.getInstance().printScreen();(function in fragment)
layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In Fragment:

Execute the code and i'd like to set layoutProgress visibility gone

Comment: Can you post part of your code? You question is incomplete.

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried so far? How is the view added? How is the Fragment added? What do you want to know in detail? You should really edit in a lot of details if you want to get a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, is this code helpfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fragment:

```
Activity act = getActivity();
if (act == null) return;
View layoutProgress = findViewById(R.id.layout_progress);
```

But really, better design would be to call a method in your `Activity` that will hide the `ProgressBar` -- as to keep all interaction with that view in one place and not get entangled in all the states if you decide to do more stuff with that progress bar.

Read the guide on [communication between Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for a proper (as in, future error-resistant) implementation of calling `Activity`'s method from a `Fragment`.

Comment: If I do this a new object is created. So if I put layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), a different view is going to be set as gone. I'd like the same view to be set as gone. Sorry if my question wasn't specifically enough.

Comment: Nope, you're only finding it here, not creating. It's the same object, you can use debugger to see for yourself :)

Comment: Where in fragment do I put this code?, I was thinking about using onAttach to solve it too, but i don't know too either, :(

Comment: *>> Execute the code and i'd like to set layoutProgress visibility gone <<* -- after you execute the code you mentioned. Any of the lifecycle methods will do, just make sure it's done on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

make your progressview global in activity
and below to access progressview in fragment

```
((Youractivity) getActivity()).layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: If I do this a new object is created. So if I put layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), a different view is going to be set as gone. I'd like the same view to be set as gone. Sorry if my question wasn't specifically enough.